# Repeater with HiddenField

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, hidden-field

I have the following HiddenField within a Repeater labeled "AdminGetAllRPT":

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="AdminGetAllRPT" runat="server" OnLoad="AdminGetAllRPT_Load">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="AdminGetAllTBL">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>Active?</td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="AdminEditLnk" runat="server" OnClick="AdminEdit_OnClick">Edit
               <asp:HiddenField ID="editAdminEmail" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("emailAddress") %>' />
               </asp:LinkButton>
           </td>
           <td><%# Eval("userName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("emailAddress") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("firstName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("lastName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("isActive") %></td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr class="alternateTemplate">
           <td>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="AdminEditLnk" runat="server" OnClick="AdminEdit_OnClick">Edit
               <asp:HiddenField ID="editAdminEmail" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("emailAddress") %>' />
               </asp:LinkButton>
           </td>
           <td><%# Eval("userName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("emailAddress") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("firstName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("lastName") %></td>
           <td><%# Eval("isActive") %></td>
       </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#">Add Administrator</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have a linkbutton that fires this code:

```
protected void AdminEdit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)AdminGetAllRPT.FindControl("editAdminEmail");
```

but the hf is coming up null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change AdminGetAllRPT.FindControl...

to

e.Item.FindControl...

Edit: Thanks for the votedown on a correct answer.

But yes e.Item.FindControl is what you want because what you're trying to do is not an event on the button, it's an event on the ItemCommand of the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater OnItemCommand="MyButtonCommandEvent" ID="AdminGetAllRPT" runat="server" OnLoad="AdminGetAllRPT_Load">
```

Then in the code-behind you can setup the event

```
void MyButtonCommandEvent(Object src, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {  
   //My event that is raised for each button pressed in the RepeaterItem
   var poo = e.Item.FindControl("myhiddenfieldid") as HiddenField;
}
```

Done...

---

To iterate over all RepeaterItems, you can have a button outside of the repeater (or maybe in the footer or something, this is not a repeater ItemCommand)

```
foreach(var item in AdminGetAllRPT.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == RepeaterItemType.Item || item.ItemType == RepeaterItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var hiddenField = item.FindControl("hiddenFieldid") as HiddenField;
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bry4n so based on the update to your question which now provides code. My answer is correct. You're just doing it wrong. You need to add a repeater ItemCommand event, remove the event from your button, and you will now get e.Item.FindControl which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Phill I apologize. I know that e.Item is used within Repeater functions. I wasn't using one but rather a regular OnClick. I will check this solution out when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @Bry4n, my initial answer was a little vague cos your question was a little vague. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Phill I didn't realize how vague it was until I woke up this morning and reread it. I blame exhaustion ha

Comment: @Phill Since I have two hidden fields its only grabbing the first one. Do I need to do a loop of some sort? I feel like this is basic and I am overlooking it. I'm stuck in coldFusion mode ha

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. So you don't want to edit a single item in the repeater, you want to edit all items? Based on your example code your button is specific to the repeater-item which is why i suggested ItemCommand. If you want to work with all items then look at my updated answer.

Comment: No I want to edit one individually. It seemed because I had DataTable ndt = new DataTable(); posted above it wasn't really populating my query. Sorry I figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One other thing, it may not be encapsulated under your edit button control.

For instance it should look like so for the find control method to work:

```
<asp:button id="AdminEdit" runat="server" onclick.... >
   <!-- Now put in your hidden field control inside (encapulated) in your button. -->
   <asp:HiddenField ID="editAdminEmail" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("emailAddress") %>' /> 
</asp:button>
```

Since AdminEdit.Controls is a container of controls, you should now be able to find that control as a first level child.   If it is not a child of the button, you will either need to make it a child, or reference it from a different method.  This is especially true for dynamically generated controls.  Ie... what control or root element is it a child of?

Comment: How would I grab that in the code behind? Using a FindControl?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the hidden field within a RepeaterItem.

```
foreach(var item in AdminGetAllRPT.Items)
{        
   var hf = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("editAdminEmail");
}
```

Comment: issue with this is that you will always get hidden field from first row of repeater.

Comment: @VinayC, this would in fact get the hidden field from every row of the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

As [jball has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435766/repeater-with-hiddenfield/4435780#4435780), you need to search at repeater item level. Where is your link button located? I believe that it should be within repeater it self (otherwise you can have multiple hidden fields (one for each repeater row) and which one is supposed to be picked up by linkbutton?). So if both link button and hidden field are in repeater then you can use code such as

```
protected void AdminEdit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var repeaterItem = ((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)repeaterItem.FindControl("editAdminEmail");
```

Comment: This works but there are multiple hiddenfields per row, so i want to capture which row that Edit button is referring to.

Comment: @Bry4n read my updated answer, you want to use a Repeater Item Command.